# Correct type declaration for mapStateToProps of Redux connect (TypeScript 2)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, typescript2.0

I have a Redux store and want to connect it. Here an extract from my container component:

```
interface IProps  {
  states: IAppState;
  actions: IAppProps;
}
// mapping state to the props
const mapStateToProps = ( state: IAppState, ownProps = {} ) => ({
  states: state
});
// mapping actions to the props
const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<IAppState> ) => ({
  actions: Redux.bindActionCreators( actions, dispatch )
});

// connect store to App
@connect<IAppState, IAppProps, any>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)
export default class App extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
//...
}
```

When compiling I receive the following issue:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(state: IAppState, ownProps?: {}) => { states: IAppState; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam<IAppState, any>'.
  Type '(state: IAppState, ownProps?: {}) => { states: IAppState; }' is not assignable to type 'MapStateToPropsFactory<IAppState, any>'.
    Type '{ states: IAppState; }' is not assignable to type 'MapStateToProps<IAppState, any>'.
      Type '{ states: IAppState; }' provides no match for the signature '(state: any, ownProps?: any): IAppState'.
```

I'm using @types/react-redux@4.4.44 that exposes MapStateToProps interface. I would think that my mapStateToProps confronts this interface... Yet something is wrong. Any ideas what is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, seems like `@types/react-redux` accepts `mapStateToProps` to return exact the same type as took in. I wanted it to modify it for props during mapping like `{ states: AppStateTree }`. Instead I've modified the state tree `combineReducers({ states: myReducer })`. So this code works fine:

```
interface IRootState {
  state: IAppState;
}

const mapStateToProps = ( state: IRootState ) => state;

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  toggleOpenAddFeed
};

type IProps = IRootState & typeof mapDispatchToProps;

class App extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-wrapper">
         <Mycomponent store={this.props} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( App );
```

Answer (score 4):

`ownProps` doesn't have any type. You must give a type to it.

```
const mapStateToProps = ( state: IAppState, ownProps: any = {} )
```

Comment: Thanks for the notion, yet it doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: Uhm that's odd. Looking at the exception, it looks like that TypeScript doesn't like how you define `states`. Try to have a look at that...

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
type CounterProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>

class Counter extends Component<CounterProps> {
    toggleCounterHandler() {
    }

    incrementHandler() {
        this.props.increment()
    }

    decrementHandler() {
        this.props.decrement()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <main className={classes.counter}>
                <h1>Redux Counter</h1>
                <div className={classes.value}>{this.props.counter}</div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.incrementHandler.bind(this)}>Increment</button>
                    <button onClick={this.decrementHandler.bind(this)}>Decrement</button>
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.toggleCounterHandler}>Toggle Counter</button>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: AppState) {
    return {
        counter: state.counter
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<AppAction>) {
    return {
        increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'increment' }),
        decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'decrement' })
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter)
```